# How to pass JSP c:set variable in Spring Controller

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, controller

I have a simple variable declared in my jsp page

```
 <html>
   <body>
     <c:set var="vehicle" scope="request" value="Car" />
     <td><a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/productsHome/vehicles">Cars</a></td>
   </body>
 </html>
```

I'm trying to access the **variable** vehicle with a value of "Car" in my Spring controller

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/vehicles", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public ModelAndView viewLaptops(@RequestParam(value = "vehicle", required = false) String    vehicleType) {

      if (vehicleType.equals("Car")) {
            // retrieve car list, return the model for car list
      }
      else if (vehicleType.equals("Truck")) {
            // retrieve truck list, return the model for truck list
      }
      System.out.println(carType);

  }
```

but I'm getting a null value. How can I achieve this one? Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the generated url as follows:

```xml
<c:set var="vehiculeURL">  
  <c:url value="productsHome/vehicles">    
    <c:param name="vehicle" value="Car"/>      
  </c:url>    
</set>  
<a href="${vehiculeURL}">Car</a>
```

Comment: Thank you but I'm still getting a null value in my controller :(

Comment: Could you check the generated URL? What does it look like?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/Spring.MVC/productsHome/vehicles , and I'm trying to print the value in my controller still a null,  System.out.println(vehicleType);

Answer (score 0):

To pass values to your .jsp from a spring controller you use the Model parameter to you function:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/vehicles", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String viewLaptops(Model model, ...) {
    model.addAttribute("Car", "Toyota");
    return "index.jsp"; //path to your file
}
```

The you will have the value "Toyota" in your jsp with key "Car" by using the following syntax:

```
<div>${Car}</div>
```

Comment: thank you for giving a sample, but i was asking, how to pass a jsp variable-value to spring controller. My mistake, I should have made the title "How to pass JSP c:set variable TO Spring Controller" not "in", sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to solve everything that I want to happen, Using the @PathVariable, I am able to map multiple url request in a single controller, assuming I have 3 href

```
<td><a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/productsHome/vehicles/Car">Cars</a></td>
<td><a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/productsHome/vehicles/Truck">Trucks</a></td>
<td><a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/productsHome/vehicles/Bike">Bike</a></td>
```

I added another **handler-method** in my controller class that will support my default mapping with **/vehicle**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/vehicles", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView viewVehicles() {

    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
    mv.setViewName("vehiclesPage");

    return mv;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/vechicles/{type}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView viewDifferentVehicles(@PathVariable("type") String type) {

    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();

    if(type.equals("Car") {
        mv.setViewName("cars"); // cars.jsp
    }
    else if (type.equals("Truck") {
        mv.setViewName("trucks"); // trucks.jsp
    }
    else if (type.equals("Bike") {
        mv.setViewName("bikes");  //bikes.jsp
    }

    return mv;
}
```

This is exactly what I want to happen, mapping different request and returning the desired view in a single handler method, I thought accessing a JSP variable with some if-else structure will solve my problem, just some random luck I stumbled upon **@PathVariable**